# Flyway Core with Spring Boot gives error Circular depends-on relationship between 'delayedFlywayInitializer' and 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: sql-server, spring, database, spring-boot, flyway

I want to import some data on the SQL server database, I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.4. I use also Hibernate to generate the tables.

I added flyway core in pom:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Created the configuration file:

```
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;

@Configuration
public class FlyWayConfiguration {

    @Bean
    FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
        return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, (f) ->{} );
    }
    
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("entityManagerFactory")
    FlywayMigrationInitializer delayedFlywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
        return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, new FlywayMigrationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
            
                flyway.migrate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I created a file on `resources/db/migration/V1_0_1__InitialData.sql`

Now I'm having this error

```
    Error creating bean with name 'delayedFlywayInitializer' defined in class path resource
    [com/ikun/mkj/config/MigrationConfiguration.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between
    'delayedFlywayInitializer' and 'entityManagerFactory' at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory
```

I don't know how to fix this, I searched for solution but couldn't make.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Hi, do you need this `@DependsOn("entityManagerFactory")`? If you remove that the problem might be solved

Comment: If I remove it the flyway is initialized before hibernate creates the tables so the script migration fails cause the tables are not created yet, so this is the problem? @MarcosBarbero

Comment: I see, but you don't need Hibernate to create your schemas you can do that using Flyway. Mixing the two will only make it more difficult for you

Comment: I need to use Hibernate to create the tables and everything else.  
Regarding flyway what else can I use for migration of data?

Comment: Although Hibernate supports that operation you don't need to use it to do so. Flyway is not only meant for data migration, it's a tool that enables you to have version control on your database, you can create tables, schemas e whatever you need related to databases using Flyway

Comment: @MarcosBarbero I want to use db to import data sequentially or update existing data so this is basically the purpose of Flyway. I used it in other project with lower versions of Spring boot but with this version  I get this error.

Comment: I understand that you want to use it that way, but that's not the purpose of it. The purpose of Flyway is to version control your database. As I already said, you do not need to use Hibernate to create your tables, you can simply rely on Flyway's features to do so.

Comment: Hi @xarqt did you figure out how to fix this? Having the same issue.

Comment: @NicolasArdison I moved the flyway files from resources/db/migration  to projectx/flywayfiles and on properties I added spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:sql, it solved the issue

Answer (score 24):

Most likely u are deferring the Datasource initializing by adding :

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization =true #set it to false
```

in your application.[yml/properties].

- Removing it, or setting to false could fix your issue

as in the reference :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html

> set spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true. This will
> defer data source initialization until after any EntityManagerFactory
> beans have been created and initialized. schema.sql can then be used
> to make additions to any schema creation performed by Hibernate and
> data.sql can be used to populate it.

And by default Flyway depends on Datasource , Datasource in defer mode will wait for EntityManagerFactory
and Ofc since we use flyway the default is to start Flyway before Jpa to ensure DB consistency

So we have a circular Dependency flyway->DS->EMF->Flyway

Comment: I still have this issue but this doesn't solve it

Comment: if u can set a sample of ur code on github

Comment: That somehow did fix the problem for me. Using SpringBoot `2.4.12`

Comment: That's it, using Spring Boot 2.7.12. I was adding Flyway after I already had used 2 databases so had that set in `application.properties`. Solved, thank you @ameen.

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried [ameen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69235286/22691506), but it alone didn't help. When I applied it, Flyway then complained there was no table to run the sql on.

I ended up having to add the following to application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = false
spring.main.allow-circular-references = true
spring.flyway.depends-on = entityManagerFactory
```

The additional two lines change the initialization order and causes Flyway to be initialized before entityManagerFactory.

I guess this is relevant for newer versions.

Spring Boot 3.1.3 here.

p.s. this seem to be a problem for Spring Boot 3.1.x up to 3.1.4 only. Versions 3.1.5 and 3.0.9 work without the need to add those settings. I believe this impacts only some versions of Spring Boot 2 too, so the easy solution is to switch off of the problematic version, if possible.