# Circular depends-on relationship between 'liquibase' and 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

i create an empty new spring boot project with Spring initializr with the dependency

```
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

when i run the project i get this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between 'liquibase' and 'entityManagerFactory'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
```

any one have an idea about this

Comment: See if this answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69235286/4028009

Answer (score 4):

I encountered same issue with Spring 2.6.6, I fixed it with same solution as below.
[Flyway Core with Spring Boot gives error Circular depends-on relationship between 'delayedFlywayInitializer' and 'entityManagerFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64990131/flyway-core-with-spring-boot-gives-error-circular-depends-on-relationship-betwee/69235286#69235286)

Most likely solved by:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=false (iso true)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31849167)

Answer (score 1):

I use this annotation in spring main application class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MainSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I haven't seen this in tutorials, this one solved my issue. But I wonder why this is not included in tutorials. What makes this line so special, do you have any idea?